# Importing .csv into dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to import a .csv file into a dict.
My trouble is that when I try to read the from dict I do not get an output?
WHY??

.csv file looks something like this:

```
F59241,GG1212
F65563,QQ434
F59226,WW343
F69215,CC434
```

That I have tried is the fllowing:

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile,)
with open('mtfile.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
DICT = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}
n = ['F59241', 'F65563', 'F59226', 'F69215']

for key in n:
    if DICT.get(key):
        print ((key) + ' : ' + DICT[key])
    else:
        print((key) + ' : ' + "Not Available")
```

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Instead of `if DICT.get(key):` use `if key in DICT` unless you really want to check if the value of that `key` is not falsey / doesn't exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The with construct *closes the file* when you exit the block.  You need to read the data within the `infile` with block first

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile,)
    DICT = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader if len(rows) == 2}
    print DICT

n = ['F59241', 'F65563', 'F59226', 'F69215']

for key in n:
    if DICT.get(key):
        print ((key) + ' : ' + DICT[key])
    else:
        print((key) + ' : ' + "Not Available")
```

Comment: Tnx for that. the missing ' was a typo on my question. what interest me is what you said about the infile. how would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

As Nirk pointed out, the `with` blocks will close the file when they exit, therefor when you try to read the file (by iterating over `reader`) it raises an error. You need to create your dictionary inside with loop, or bring the contents of the file into memory. My suggestion would be the following:

```
from csv import reader
with open('myfile.csv',mode='r') as infile:
    d = dict(reader(infile))

>>> d
{'F59226': 'WW343', 'F65563': 'QQ434', 'F59241': 'GG1212', 'F69215': 'CC434'}
```